# Can't upload files Yosemite Apache

Tags: mysql, apache, magento, permissions, osx-yosemite

been trying to sort out this bug for the last few hours and can't seem to find what the problem is. I believe its probably user permissions, but not 100% what im doing wrong - or not doing right.

As of current i have apache and mysql running on OS X 10.10 Yosemite, i have virtual hosts turned on and pointing at my sites folder e.g. /user/Sites/sitename/httpdocs

I have magento & wordpress running fine on this, however i can't upload or add any files via the file upload in the backend of any of the sites i have installed.

Here is a user:group permissions i have:

```
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www   10679 28 Apr 12:03 LICENSE.html
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www   10410 28 Apr 12:03 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www   10421 28 Apr 12:03 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www  585086 28 Apr 12:15 RELEASE_NOTES.txt
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    2812 28 Apr 14:08 api.php
drwxrwxr-x+  9 _www  _www     306 28 May 15:49 app
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    2806 28 Apr 14:08 cron.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www     717 28 Apr 12:15 cron.sh
drwxrwxr-x+ 13 _www  _www     442 13 May 16:14 downloader
drwxrwxr-x+ 10 _www  _www     340 13 May 16:13 errors
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    1150 28 Apr 12:03 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    5953 28 Apr 14:08 get.php
drwxrwxr-x+  4 _www  _www     136 13 May 16:13 includes
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    2617 28 Apr 14:08 index.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    2341 28 Apr 14:08 index.php.sample
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    6416 28 Apr 14:08 install.php
drwxrwxr-x+ 17 _www  _www     578 28 May 14:26 js
drwxrwxr-x+ 15 _www  _www     510 13 May 16:13 lib
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www    1319 28 Apr 12:15 mage
drwxrwxrwx+ 11 _www  _www     374 28 May 15:42 media
drwxrwxr-x+ 31 _www  _www    1054 14 May 08:50 old
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 _www  _www     886 28 Apr 12:03 php.ini.sample
drwxrwxr-x+  5 _www  _www     170 13 May 16:14 pkginfo
drwxrwxr-x+  6 _www  _www     204 13 May 16:14 shell
drwxrwxr-x+  5 _www  _www     170 18 May 14:52 skin
drwxrwxrwx+ 10 _www  _www     340 26 May 14:28 var
```

They are either 777 or 755 just because I thought that they are the problem, so setting them to those means something might work. But nothing.

Would be great if anyone has any idea.

Cheers.

Comment: Most of the uploads in the admin wysiwyg go into media subdirectories so make sure those subdirectories are writeable by the Apache user or group. Also check to make sure your Apache user and group is _www (it is on mine Macports apache2, not the default Apache that comes with Mac OS).

Comment: Thanks the sub directories are all 777 - how do i check the correct user?

Comment: I found out how to get the user: 

ps aux | grep apache  - and then how to get the associated groups with this user -  group Username - but changing to this still hasn't solved my problem.